# Concept of Stationary Population

Tags: self-study, references, demography, mortality

In stationary population, there can be different probabilities for death in a given year for different age groups but these probabilities don't change over time. So the probability a 28 year old will die in the next year is the same year to year.

**My question** is:  In real life, is it usual to have same age-specific probabilities of death over time? I suppose so. Because if no war or epidemic happens, then the age-specific probabilities of death can be same year to year. Am I wrong? Is the assumption of same age-specific probabilities of death not the real scenario? Is stationary population concept completely theoretical? If it is hypothetical, then why have demographers developed the concept of stationary population? What is the advantage of stationary population? What do demographers establish by considering stationary population?

Comment: Social and ecological change are more or less ongoing, and translate into different and ever-changing distributions of disease and mortality. Lewontin, R., & Levins, R. (1996). [The return of old diseases and the appearance of new ones](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1080/10455759609358683). *Capitalism, Nature, Socialism*, 7(2), 103–108.

Comment: Part of the reason why *assume things don't change* can be useful (including in demography), is because the relevant rates of change may be slow relative to other parts of the world that we care about (e.g., funding decisions over the next year or two). An example outside of biology is the Earth's magnetic pole, which is still used in shipping navigation under a long-working assumption of *it's not really changing*, but [recent change has been so dramatic that a revision of the previous working assumption is now necessary](https://boingboing.net/2018/01/31/the-earths-magnetic-poles-ma.html).